# d3 - achieving replay

Tags: javascript, d3.js

This question is on d3 v5.

I'm trying to implement multiple synchronous transitions for a fixed duration in using d3, but with **keyframe data coming from user data in arrays** rather than d3 interpolations. (**Edit**) In other words, I'm trying to achieve a replay based on data, rather than interpolated transitions.

I've tried to write up the question as an example below.

```js
var arr1=d3.range(0,1000), arr2=d3.range(0,10000),
  one=d3.select("#one"), two=d3.select("#two");

var duration=5000; // 5 seconds

// TBD:
// Synchronously Update "one" and "two" continously with the individual values of 
// arr1 and arr2 respectively for a total duration of "duration"
// 
// Obviously "two" should be updated faster than "one" during the duration
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="one">Update arr1 here</div>
<div id="two">Update arr2 here</div>
```

In my real use case, I have to update many charts (each drawn on it's own `canvas`) synchronously. Don't have to necessarily do this in d3, but I figured given that d3 can tackle several transitions at once with interpolations, there must be something in there to solve this.

Comment: Are you wanting to insert numbers as text or adjust the width of the divs like bar-graphs?

Comment: The "insert numbers as text" is just a simple placeholder to simulate actual changes to each canvas chart, based on data in the array. The answer could simply update the html of each div to the array value.

Answer (score 0):

If you're wanting to animate the divs like bar graphs, here is a makeshift solution:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style>
        div {
            width: 0%;
            min-height: 10px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="one"></div>
<div id="two"></div>

<button onClick="update()">update</button>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<script>
var arr1=d3.range(0,1000), arr2=d3.range(0,10000),
one=d3.select("#one"), two=d3.select("#two");

var duration=5000; // 5 seconds

function update() {
    one.style("transition", "width " + (duration/1000) + "s")
        .style("background", "blue")
        .style("width", (arr1.pop()/9) + "px");
    two.style("transition", "width " + (duration/1000) + "s")
        .style("background", "blue")
        .style("width", (arr2.pop()/9) + "px");
}

// TBD:
// Synchronously Update "one" and "two" continously with the individual values of 
// arr1 and arr2 respectively for a total duration of "duration"
// 
// Obviously "two" should be updated faster than "one" during the duration
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, appreciate your time. However as I clarified, this is a data replay using JavaScript question, rather than css transitions.